# Getting liquibase changeLog Details programatically in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I have a requirement where I have to show the  current **liquibase-changelog** version as  part of /actuator/info.

Is there any spring Auto config component which can be provide me these details?

Basically  I need couple of columns from **databasechangelog** table which is part of changeset.

Comment: There is org.springframework.boot.actuate.liquibase.LiquibaseEndpoint . Does it fits your needs? Could you describe what exact data you want to expose?

Comment: .Ya I  have seen this.But unable to @Autoconfigure It. It says ,no qualified  BEAN PRESENT.  My requirement is to display the  ID column from databasechangelog table as part of my actuator/info.

Comment: As part of changeset ,there is a ID column which I need to access.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work...

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import liquibase.changelog.RanChangeSet;
import liquibase.database.Database;
import liquibase.database.DatabaseConnection;
import liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory;
import liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection;
import liquibase.exception.DatabaseException;
import liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase;

@Component
public class LiquibaseService {

    @Autowired
    private SpringLiquibase springLiquibase;

    public List<RanChangeSet> getRanChangeSetList() throws SQLException, DatabaseException {
        try (Connection c = springLiquibase.getDataSource().getConnection()) {
            DatabaseConnection liquibaseConnection = new JdbcConnection(c);
            Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(liquibaseConnection);

            if (StringUtils.trimToNull(springLiquibase.getDefaultSchema()) != null) {
                if (database.supportsSchemas()) {
                    database.setDefaultSchemaName(springLiquibase.getDefaultSchema());
                } else if (database.supportsCatalogs()) {
                    database.setDefaultCatalogName(springLiquibase.getDefaultSchema());
                }
            }
            if (StringUtils.trimToNull(springLiquibase.getLiquibaseSchema()) != null) {
                if (database.supportsSchemas()) {
                    database.setLiquibaseSchemaName(springLiquibase.getLiquibaseSchema());
                } else if (database.supportsCatalogs()) {
                    database.setLiquibaseCatalogName(springLiquibase.getLiquibaseSchema());
                }
            }
            if (StringUtils.trimToNull(springLiquibase.getLiquibaseTablespace()) != null
                    && database.supportsTablespaces()) {
                database.setLiquibaseTablespaceName(springLiquibase.getLiquibaseTablespace());
            }
            if (StringUtils.trimToNull(springLiquibase.getDatabaseChangeLogTable()) != null) {
                database.setDatabaseChangeLogTableName(springLiquibase.getDatabaseChangeLogTable());
            }
            if (StringUtils.trimToNull(springLiquibase.getDatabaseChangeLogLockTable()) != null) {
                database.setDatabaseChangeLogLockTableName(springLiquibase.getDatabaseChangeLogLockTable());
            }
            return database.getRanChangeSetList();
        }
    }

}
```

A RanChangeSet should have all the information you need...

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/changelog/RanChangeSet.java